# Виджет view перекрывает рабочую область приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Делаю автокликер на android. Делаю виджеты для свайпа. Вот такой вот класс 3 виджета. WidgMiddleView рисует линию между WidgStartView и WidgEndView все работает, только WidgMiddleView полностью перекрывает экран и я не могу ни по чем кликнуть. Что делать как это избежать.

```
class SwipeWidgView(var ctx: Context, var mainWidget: MainWidgetView, var key: String?): View(ctx) {

    protected lateinit var paramsStartWidg: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    protected lateinit var paramsEndWidg: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    protected lateinit var paramsMiddleWidg: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    protected lateinit var widgetWindowManager: WidgetWindowManager
    protected lateinit var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater
    private lateinit var widgStartView: WidgStartView
    private lateinit var widgEndView: WidgEndView
    private lateinit var widgMiddleView: WidgMiddleView
    var scenarioClick: ScenarioClick? = null
    val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    var lstInitMedium: MutableList<Boolean> = mutableListOf(false, false)

    init {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
        widgetWindowManager = WidgetWindowManager.init(ctx)
        paramsStartWidg = initParams()
        paramsEndWidg = initParams()
        paramsMiddleWidg = initParams()
        paramsMiddleWidg.flags = paramsMiddleWidg.flags or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
        widgStartView = WidgStartView(ctx)
        widgEndView = WidgEndView(ctx)
        widgMiddleView = WidgMiddleView(ctx)
        setupData()
    }

    fun setupData() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            if (key.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                var newKey = mainWidget.getRandomString()
                var name = mainWidget.getName()
                var date = Constants.getDateMilliNow()
                var posQueue = mainWidget.getNextPos()
                scenarioClick = ScenarioClick(
                    null, widgStartView.posX, widgStartView.posY,
                    widgEndView.posX, widgEndView.posY, Constants.TYPE_SWIPE, name,
                    posQueue, newKey, date
                )
                mainWidget.addScenarioClick(scenarioClick!!)
            } else {
                //Request to db later
            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                widgStartView.setWidgText(scenarioClick!!.posQueue.toString())
                showWidgets()
            }
        }
    }

    fun drawLine(width: Int, height: Int) {
        scenarioClick?.let { sc ->
            try {
                var startX = sc.posX2!! + (width / 2)
                var startY = sc.posY2!! + (height / 2)
                var endX = sc.posX + (width / 2)
                var endY = sc.posY + (height / 2)
                widgMiddleView.binding.rootWidg.layoutParams.width = abs(startX - endX)
                widgMiddleView.binding.rootWidg.layoutParams.height = abs(startY - endY)
                widgMiddleView.binding.rootWidg.drawLine2(endX, endY, startX, startY)
                mainHandler.postDelayed({
                    widgMiddleView.invalidate()
                }, 1000)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                L.i("exception=" + e.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    fun showWidgets() {
        widgMiddleView.showWidget()
        widgStartView.showWidget()
        widgEndView.showWidget()
        //while(true) {
        /*mainHandler.postDelayed({
            var left = scenarioClick!!.posX
            var top = scenarioClick!!.posY
            var right = scenarioClick!!.posX2
            var bottom = scenarioClick!!.posY2
            if(right != null && bottom != null) {
                widgMiddleView.changeRectCoords(left, top, right!!, bottom!!)
            }
        }, 300L)*/
        //  }

        //widgetWindowManager.addView(widgMiddleView, paramsMiddleWidg)
    }

    fun endInitMiddleWidgView() {
        if (lstInitMedium[0] && lstInitMedium[1]) {
            drawLine(widgStartView.width2, widgStartView.height2)
        }
    }

    fun initParams(): WindowManager.LayoutParams {
        var typeApp = 0
        typeApp = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        }

        var params: WindowManager.LayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            typeApp,  //вот тут менять не проепать
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        params!!.gravity =
            Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
        return params
    }

    inner class WidgStartView(ctx: Context) : FrameLayout(ctx) {
        lateinit var binding: WidgSwipeStartBinding
        var width2: Int = -1
        var height2: Int = -1
        var xm = 0
        var ym = 0
        var modeNow = 0
        var posX: Int = 0
            set(value) {
                field = value
                paramsStartWidg?.let {
                    it.x = value
                }
                scenarioClick?.let {
                    it.posX = value
                }
            }
            get() {
                return field
            }
        var posY: Int = 0
            set(value) {
                field = value
                paramsStartWidg?.let {
                    it.y = value
                }
                scenarioClick?.let {
                    it.posY = value
                }
            }
            get() {
                return field
            }

        init {
            binding = WidgSwipeStartBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


            binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
                ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    // Убираем слушателя, чтобы избежать лишних вызовов
                    binding.root.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    // Теперь вы можете получить реальные значения width, height, x и y
                    L.i("zvezda")
                    var centerDisp = mainWidget.widgetWindowManager.getCenterDisplay()
                    width2 = binding.root.width
                    height2 = binding.root.height
                    posX = centerDisp.first - (width2 / 2)
                    posY = centerDisp.second - (height2 / 2)
                    mainWidget.changePos(scenarioClick!!, posX, posY)
                    widgetWindowManager.updateView(binding.rootWidg, paramsStartWidg)
                    // Выводим значения в консоль
                    /*L.i(
                        "widgetView.x=" + binding.root.x + "widgetView.y=" + binding.root.y +
                                "widgetView.top=" + binding.root.top + "widgetView.left=" + binding.root.left +
                                "widgetView.trX=" + binding.root.translationX + "widgetView.trY=" + binding.root.translationY +
                                "widgWidth=" + binding.root.width + "widthL=" + binding.root.layoutParams.width +
                                "ppp=" + binding.root.top
                    )*/
                    lstInitMedium[0] = true
                    endInitMiddleWidgView()
                    //widgEndView.showWidget()
                }
            })

            //Touch listener
            binding.rootWidg.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener {
                private var initialX = 0
                private var initialY = 0
                private var initialTouchX = 0f
                private var initialTouchY = 0f
                override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    //L.i("This is it");
                    var x = event!!.rawX
                    var y = event.rawY
                    L.i("control pizda xraw=" + x + "yraw=" + y + "x=" + event.x + "y=" + event.y + "|")
                    when (event.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            xm = v!!.width / 2
                            ym = v.height / 2
                            modeNow = MainWidgetView.MODE_MOVE
                            initialX = paramsStartWidg.x
                            initialY = paramsStartWidg.y
                            //get the touch location
                            initialTouchX = event.rawX
                            initialTouchY = event.rawY
                            return true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                            if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_MOVE) {
                                L.i("Pizda")
                                posX = initialX + (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                                posY = initialY + (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                               /* paramsStartWidg.x = posX
                                paramsStartWidg.y = posY*/
                               // mainWidget.changePos(scenarioClick!!, posX, posY)
                                //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                                widgetWindowManager.updateView(binding.rootWidg, paramsStartWidg)
                                drawLine(width2, height2)
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_RESIZE) {
                                //resize2(event.x, event.y, v!!.width, v.height)
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_VISIBILITY) {
                                //changeOpacity(event.x, event.y, v!!.width, v.height)
                            }
                            return true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                            //resize2(event.getX(), event.getY(),v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), root_container, moveView);
                            if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_MOVE) {
                                val Xdiff = (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                                val Ydiff = (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_RESIZE) {
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_VISIBILITY) {
                            }
                            modeNow = 0
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
            })
        }

        fun setWidgText(text: String) {
            binding.tvClickWidg.text = text
        }

        fun showWidget() {
            widgetWindowManager.addView(binding.root, paramsStartWidg)
        }
    }

    inner class WidgEndView(ctx: Context) : FrameLayout(ctx) {
        var width2: Int = -1
        var height2: Int = -1
        var xm = 0
        var ym = 0
        var modeNow = 0
        lateinit var binding: WidgSwipeEndBinding
        var posX: Int = 0
            set(value) {
                field = value
                paramsEndWidg?.let {
                    it.x = value
                }
                scenarioClick?.let {
                    it.posX2 = value
                }
            }
            get() {
                return field
            }
        var posY: Int = 0
            set(value) {
                field = value
                paramsEndWidg?.let {
                    it.y = value
                }
                scenarioClick?.let {
                    it.posY2 = value
                }
            }
            get() {
                return field
            }

        init {
            binding = WidgSwipeEndBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
                ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    // Убираем слушателя, чтобы избежать лишних вызовов
                    binding.root.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    width2 = binding.root.width
                    height2 = binding.root.height
                    var centerDisp = mainWidget.widgetWindowManager.getCenterDisplay()
                    posX = centerDisp.first - (width2/2)
                    posY = centerDisp.second - (height/2) - (centerDisp.second * 0.3).toInt()
                    mainWidget.changePos2(scenarioClick!!, posX, posY)
                    widgetWindowManager.updateView(binding.rootWidg, paramsEndWidg)
                    // Выводим значения в консоль
                    /*L.i(
                        "widgetView.x=" + binding.root.x + "widgetView.y=" + binding.root.y +
                                "widgetView.top=" + binding.root.top + "widgetView.left=" + binding.root.left +
                                "widgetView.trX=" + binding.root.translationX + "widgetView.trY=" + binding.root.translationY +
                                "widgWidth=" + binding.root.width + "widthL=" + binding.root.layoutParams.width +
                                "ppp=" + binding.root.top
                    )*/
                    lstInitMedium[1] = true
                    endInitMiddleWidgView()
                    //widgMiddleView.showWidget()
                }
            })

            //Touch listener
            binding.rootWidg.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener {
                private var initialX = 0
                private var initialY = 0
                private var initialTouchX = 0f
                private var initialTouchY = 0f
                override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                    //L.i("This is it");
                    var x = event!!.rawX
                    var y = event.rawY
                    L.i("control pizda xraw=" + x + "yraw=" + y + "x=" + event.x + "y=" + event.y + "|")
                    when (event.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            xm = v!!.width / 2
                            ym = v.height / 2
                            modeNow = MainWidgetView.MODE_MOVE
                            initialX = paramsEndWidg.x
                            initialY = paramsEndWidg.y
                            //get the touch location
                            initialTouchX = event.rawX
                            initialTouchY = event.rawY
                            return true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                            if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_MOVE) {
                                L.i("Pizda")
                                posX = initialX + (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                                posY = initialY + (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                                /*paramsEndWidg.x = posX
                                paramsEndWidg.y = posY*/
                                mainWidget.changePos2(scenarioClick!!, posX, posY)
                                //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                                widgetWindowManager.updateView(binding.rootWidg, paramsEndWidg)
                                drawLine(width2, height2)
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_RESIZE) {
                                //resize2(event.x, event.y, v!!.width, v.height)
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_VISIBILITY) {
                                //changeOpacity(event.x, event.y, v!!.width, v.height)
                            }
                            return true
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                            //resize2(event.getX(), event.getY(),v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), root_container, moveView);
                            if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_MOVE) {
                                val Xdiff = (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                                val Ydiff = (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_RESIZE) {
                            } else if (modeNow == MainWidgetView.MODE_VISIBILITY) {
                            }
                            modeNow = 0
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    return false
                }
            })
        }

        fun showWidget() {
            widgetWindowManager.addView(binding.root, paramsEndWidg)
        }
    }

    inner class WidgMiddleView(ctx: Context) : RectangleView(ctx) {
        var width2: Int = -1
        var height2: Int = -1
        lateinit var binding: WidgSwipeMiddleBinding

        init {
            alpha = 0.8f
            binding = WidgSwipeMiddleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            binding.root.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
                ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    // Убираем слушателя, чтобы избежать лишних вызовов
                    //binding.root.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    width2 = binding.root.width
                    height2 = binding.root.height
                    // Выводим значения в консоль
                    L.i(
                        "widgetView.x=" + binding.root.x + "widgetView.y=" + binding.root.y +
                                "widgetView.top=" + binding.root.top + "widgetView.left=" + binding.root.left +
                                "widgetView.trX=" + binding.root.translationX + "widgetView.trY=" + binding.root.translationY +
                                "widgWidth=" + binding.root.width + "widthL=" + binding.root.layoutParams.width +
                                "ppp=" + binding.root.top
                    )
                    lstInitMedium[1] = true
                    endInitMiddleWidgView()
                    //widgMiddleView.showWidget()
                }
            })
        }

       /* fun changeRectCoords(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
            // if(scenarioClick!!.posX2 != null && scenarioClick!!.posY2 != null)
            binding.rootWidg.drawLine(left, top, right, bottom)
        }*/

        fun showWidget() {

            //changeRectCoords(scenarioClick!!.posX, scenarioClick!!.posY, scenarioClick!!.posX2!!, scenarioClick!!.posY2!!)
            widgetWindowManager.addView(binding.root, paramsMiddleWidg)
        }
    }


}
```

RectangleView

```
public class RectangleView extends View {

    private Rect rect = new Rect();
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public RectangleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RectangleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RectangleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        int color = Color.parseColor("#0CFFE5");
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(rect != null) {
            canvas.drawLine(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, mPaint);
        }
    }

    public void drawLine2(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        rect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        postInvalidate();
    }

}
```

разметка виджета

```
<net.mautoclicker.ui.views.RectangleView
        android:id="@+id/rootWidg"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"/>
```